Singleton Selenium Chromedriver randomly decides not to connect, What could be the culprit
I have a problem with python selenium's chromedriver connection.About half the time I run my tests to connect to a server I am hosting, selenium throwws a connection timed out error like this
tests\certificate\test_mysoftware_Netwrk_ClientGroup.py:56: in setup_method
    delete_testClients()
lib\mysoftware_ClientGroup.py:195: in delete_testClients
    driver.get(website_url)
venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:363: in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:354: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:229: in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
E     (Session info: chrome=128.0.6613.114)
E   Stacktrace:
E       GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF72A7BB652+29090]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A72E709]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5EB1CA]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5E3204]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D4179]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D5F42]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D443F]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D3CD1]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D3C10]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D1AD3]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5D214C]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A5EE231]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A6873FE]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A6666EA]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A6865D9]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A666493]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A6309B1]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A631B11]
E       GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF72AAD8CDD+3295277]
E       GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF72AB248C3+3605523]
E       GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF72AB1A787+3564247]
E       GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF72A876F36+797318]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A73988F]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A735474]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A735600]
E       (No symbol) [0x00007FF72A724A9F]
E       BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB1DDD7374+20]
E       RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB1FADCC91+33]

I initially thought this might be from version missmatch so I set both google chrome and chromedriver versions to 128.0.6613.114. I thought that solved the issue but it is persisting.
I am using selenium 4.18.1 with python 3.10 on a windows 10 machine. While half of the time these errors are comming from specific set of tests.
I am using following driver options
def get_driver_options():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1440, 900")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--FontRenderHinting[none]")
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    options.add_argument('--remote-allow-origins=*')
    options.add_argument('--disable-search-engine-choice-screen')
    return options

Also I am using a singleton webdriver class to keep my tests from getting too much memory.
class SdriverMeta(type):
    _instances =  {}
    _lock: Lock = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            #with cls._lock:

            #if cls not in cls._instances:
            try:

                instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
                cls._instances[cls] = instance
            except Exception as e:
                # Ensure that the lock and instance are properly cleaned up
                if cls in cls._instances:
                    del cls._instances[cls]
                raise
        return cls._instances[cls]

    @classmethod
    def get_lock(cls):
        return cls._lock

    @classmethod
    def reset_instance(cls):
        # This method can be called to reset the Singleton instance
        with cls._lock:
            if cls in cls._instances:
                del cls._instances[cls]

class SDriver(metaclass=SdriverMeta):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls,headless = True):
        if not hasattr(cls, "_instance") or cls._instance is None:
            with cls._lock:

                cls._instance = super(SDriver, cls).__new__(cls)
                cls._instance.headless = headless
                cls._instance.driver = None


        return cls._instance

    def get_driver(self,headless = True):
        #self.close_driver()
        with SdriverMeta.get_lock():


            if self.driver is None:
                if headless:
                    options = get_driver_options()
                else:
                    options = get_driver_headfull_options()
                service = Service()
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options) 
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(90)
        return self.driver


    def close_driver(self):
        with SdriverMeta.get_lock():

            if hasattr(self, "driver") and self.driver:
                try:
                    self.driver.close()
                    self.driver.quit()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to close the driver: {e}")
                finally:
                    self.driver = None
        SdriverMeta.reset_instance()
                    #SDriver._instance = None

     

And the error part happens here as I try to get the url of my server:

def delete_testClients():
        sdriver = SDriver()
        headless=True
        driver = sdriver.get_driver(headless)
        website_url = default_config["website_url"]
        driver.get(website_url)

So as it stands I have no Idea what could be causing my webdriver to not to connect to the server address I have for the machine I have. The url is correct as I am getting it from the hosting service and I am using the same json for all the other tests that are working.
The code snippet I posted works half of the time. Other half of the time the singleton driver sdriver cannot establish a connection to the server that I am testing. I have an inkling that this problem is related with the singleton driver but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.
Update 1: I don't think that the problem is with the driver settings. If that was the case 30 other tests that use the same driver options would give simmilar errors.

to debug simplify the code and remove all preferences.  Check to see that it works that way.  Then add the preferences/options you need one at a time.  There's really no need for complicated Singleton logic here as it's basically a script... you create a driver, run your sequence of driver actions, and then quit the driver.  (only use quit() method... close is not needed and some drivers may quit if close closes the last opened tab.)

@browsermator Hey Sorry about previous answer. The same error just came up again and I am once more lost on what to do.

@browsermator Had the right solution. Problem was with these driver options.
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'") options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
Once I removed them my script works fine! Thank you.
